# Utilizing RTC Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, rational-team-concert

I'm wondering if RTC dashboard provides a closed set of predefined charts? 
Do you know if I can utilize it and create any kind of charts I need, from any given source of data?
I couldn't answer that even after reading RTC website

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if RTC dashboard provides a closed set of predefined charts?

Yes, there are widgets done for displaying charts, as you can see [in this example](https://jazz.net/products/rational-team-concert/features/report#dashboard-health):

[image: https://jazz.net/products/rational-team-concert/images/dashboard-glance.png]

You can [add as many widget](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=//com.ibm.jazz.dashboard.doc/topics/t_add_viewlet.html) as you want.

To create your own chart or widget, you can follow "[How to create dashboard viewlets in Rational Team Concert](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/10/createdashboardviewletsinrationalteamconcert/index.html)".